# excel vba vlookup if true then message box

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am a bit confused on how to properly do a vlookup in VBA within a module.

I want to take the value a cell

Range("G6").Value

and compare it to a range on sheet2

A6:J2000

if it finds a match in column 1 and column 10 = true then display a message box.

Update here is the code I have tried.

```
Dim sRes As String

sRes = Application.VLookup(G6, Sheet2.Range("A6:J2000"), 2)

MsgBox sRes
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to just valuate the output of the VLOOKUP (*how to do a vlookup in vba is well documented*). What have you tried/researched? Do you have any code for us to review?

Comment: `Application.Vlookup(...)` is a good place to start

Comment: I have looked at Application.Vlookup, but I am missing something. I have updated my post to include the code I am trying

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. `G6` means something to Excel, not to VBA. Once you add `Option Explicit`, you'll find VBA complains about `G6` being an undeclared variable. What you want is `Sheet2.Range("G6").Value`, not "G6".

Comment: like this: sRes = Application.VLookup(Sheet3.Range("G6").Value, Sheet3.Range("A6:J2000"), 1, False)   - As that does not work Sheet 3 is the cell to compare to, sheet 2 is the range to lookup

Answer (score 0):

ok I figure it out. Here is the working code:

```
Dim sRes As String

celllookup = Range("R6").Value
sRes = Application.VLookup(celllookup, Sheet5.Range("A6:J2000"), 10, False)

If sResult = "TRUE" Then
    MsgBox "Its True"
End If
```